# how can I end the program based on the user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a calculator using functions, but I am really not sure what am I doing wrong here. When the user types n/N the program does not end but continues from the else statement in operation_outcome() function. Seems the next_example() function works fine when the user wants another example, but I am not sure either if the code is written proper way here

```
def enter_number(num, error):
    notEntered = True
    while notEntered:
        try:
            num = float(input(num))
            notEntered = False

        except ValueError:
            print(error)

        else:
            return num


def operation_outcome(first_num, second_num, choice, error):
    notEntered = True
    while notEntered:
        print("1. addition")
        print("2. subtraction")
        print("3. multiplication")
        print("4. division")

        try:
            choice = int(input(choice))
            if choice >= 1 and choice <= 4:
                if choice == 1:
                    print("the answer is", first_num + second_num)

            elif choice == 2:
                print("the answer is", first_num - second_num)

            elif choice == 3:
                print("the answer is", first_num * second_num)

            elif choice == 4:
                 try:
                    print("the answer is", first_num / second_num)
                 except ZeroDivisionError:
                     print("you cant divide by zero")

            next_example("do you want another example? y/n: ")

        except ValueError:
            print(error)

        else:
            print(error)
            operation_outcome(first_num, second_num, "enter a choice: ", "enter the right value!"
        )

            

def next_example(answer):
    notEntered = True
    while notEntered:
        answer = input(answer)

        if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
            first_num = enter_number("enter 1. number: ", "enter the right value!")
            second_num = enter_number("enter 2. number: ", "enter the right value!")
            operation_outcome(  first_num, second_num, "enter a choice: ", "enter the right value!"
        )
          

        elif answer == "n" or answer == "N":
            print("end of the program.")
            return False

        else:
            print("enter the right value!")


first_num = enter_number("enter 1. number: ", "enter the right value!")
second_num = enter_number("enter 2. number: ", "enter the right value!")
operation_outcome(first_num, second_num, "enter a choice: ", "enter the right value!")
```

Comment: First step when you encounter problems is to reproduce them in isolation ([mcve]) or to run them in a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exit()` to stop execution. Do that instead of `return False` and you should be good to go

```
elif answer == "n" or answer == "N":
    print("end of the program.")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two functions.

One is used to prompt the user to enter an integer value and ensure that the value entered is usable - i.e., is an integer

Create another function to get the options i.e., addition, subtraction, multiplication or division. Allow for a get-out option. Let's call it X (or x)

Then you just need a loop to carry out the calculations and present the results.

Something like this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

options = {
    '1': ('addition', add, '+'),
    '2': ('subtraction', sub, '-'),
    '3': ('multiplication', mul, '*'),
    '4': ('division', truediv, '/'),
    'x': ('exit', None, None)
}

def getval(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

def getoption():
    while True:
        for k, (o, *_) in options.items():
            print(f'{k}) {o}')
        option = input()
        try:
            return options[option]
        except KeyError:
            print('Invalid option')

while (option := getoption()) != options['x']:
    x = getval('X: ')
    y = getval('Y: ')
    _, func, symbol = option
    print(f'{x} {symbol} {y} = {func(x, y)}')
```